# Calendar plugin not displaying nav arrows in mobile browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, plugins

I am using an Availability Calendar plugin on my small cabin rental website, for which I am building a mobile version of (using Bootstrap).

The arrows appear fine above the calendars on the desktop site [here](http://www.stonesthrowchateau.com/rates.html),

but they do not appear in the mobile page [here](http://www.stonesthrowchateau.com/mobile/index.html) (note that they do seem to appear and function correctly in desktop browsers, just not in mobile browsers).

Any assistance or advice anyone could provide here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
k

Comment: they seem to work fine for me

Comment: In your mobile browser? I'm looking at iOS Safari and the arrows are definitely not showing up.

Comment: Hmm...strange. Works for me in mobile with Safari. Works in Chrome as well. Is your browser updated?

Comment: Yeah, just checked. Browsers are all updated, still no arrows. Weird.

Comment: That is strange. Maybe If you posted the code it would be easier to figure out what is going on. When you open the page in Chrome/Firefox, do you see any errors in the console?